# Interrogating Word & Open Office Writer Files for Merge Fields

Tags: merge, ms-word, docx, mailmerge, openoffice-writer

Are tools readily available for interrogating Word and/or Open Office Writer files programatically to identify merge field tokens conveniently and replace the tokens with data values? For example, scanning MYDOC.DOCX to find <> and <> among the text and substituting values "JONES" and "PAT"

Comment: You can use inbuilt VBA for that. Openoffice has something similar.

Comment: Have you done a search for mail merge on the web?  There is quite a bit of documentation available, for example http://davidmburke.com/2011/08/10/mail-merge-in-libreoffice/.